# Git push shows me irrelevant folder after push

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-push

I've created a brand new repo, and I've followed the below to commit/push my code to the new repo.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin <project url>
git push -f origin master
```

However after pushing it, my directory structure looks somehow irrelevant compared to my local structure. (See attachment below)

[image: In Github page]

This (the folder marked in red) should have been a folder just like "server" (which comes next to it). What could be wrong with my push? Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a subrepository.

Comment: @tkausl Strange thing is, If I click it, again the same structure appears, it keeps on repeating as much time as you click it :(